# C File processing and matching help

Tags: c

I have an assignment in college in which we are required to read in two .dat (aascii) files that we created with an earlier program, both of which are sorted.

One is a client account file  which contains the clients balance and account number and name, the other is a transaction file that contains the account number and the transactions for that account.

This program has to match the account numbers and create a new and updated clients file by adding the transaction amount to the balance of the client based on the accounts number.

I have this working fine except for when there is a duplicate transaction for example if the transaction file contains 2 separate transactions for the 2nd client my code will print the updated balance after both transactions instead of a cumulative balance.

I am just wondering if anyone can shed any light on how to solve this problem. My code is attached, thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int account,matches=0;     /* account number */
    char date[ 30 ]; /* account Date */
    double balance, saleamount,total=0, x;  /* account SaleAmount */
    int transaccount;
    char name [ 30 ];



    FILE *cfPtr;     /* cfPtr = clients.dat file pointer */
    FILE *ctPtr;    /* cfPtr = transaction.dat file pointer */
    FILE *cfPtr2;    /* cfPtr2 = new client file */

    cfPtr2 = fopen( "clientupdate.dat", "w" );

    /* fopen opens file; exits program if file cannot be opened */ 
    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "clients.dat", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "clients could not be opened\n" );
        fflush(stdin);
    } /* end if */
    else
        if( ( ctPtr = fopen( "transactions.dat", "r" ) ) == NULL)
        {
            printf( "File could not be opened\n" );
            fflush(stdin);
        }
    else { /* read account, date,name, balance and SaleAmount from files */
        fscanf( cfPtr, "%d%s%lf", &account, &name, &balance );
        fflush(stdin);

        fscanf( ctPtr, "%d%s%lf", &transaccount, &date, &saleamount );
        fflush(stdin);

        printf( "%-13s%-10s%s\n", "  Account", "Name", "Balance" );
        printf("|----------------------------------|\n");
        while( !feof(ctPtr))
        {   

            while( !feof(cfPtr) &&matches==0 )
            {   

                if(account == transaccount)
                {
                   matches=1;
                    total=0;
                    x = balance+saleamount;
                    total = total + x;
                    balance = total; 

                printf("  %-10d%-10s%.2lf\n", account, name, total);
                }
                else
                {

                    fscanf( cfPtr, "%d%s%lf", &account, &name, &balance );
                    fflush(stdin);
                }   

            }
            fprintf( cfPtr2, "%d %s %.2lf\n", account, name, total );
            fscanf( ctPtr, "%d%s%lf", &transaccount, &date, &saleamount );
            fflush(stdin);
           matches=0;

        }

        fclose( cfPtr2 );
        getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from pax and a good while playing with my own code i came up with this working solution. Thanks again for the help , Much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{ 
    int account;     /* account number */
    char date[ 30 ]; /* account Date */
    double balance, saleamount; /* account SaleAmount */
    int transaccount;
    char name [ 30 ];
    int newaccount;
    char newname[ 30];
    double newbalance;
    int match=0;



    FILE *cfPtr;     /* cfPtr = clients.dat file pointer */
    FILE *ctPtr;    /* cfPtr = transaction.dat file pointer */
    FILE *cfPtr2;    /* cfPtr2 = new client file */

    cfPtr2 = fopen( "clientupdate.dat", "w" );

    /* fopen opens file; exits program if file cannot be opened */ 
    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "clients.dat", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "clients could not be opened\n" );

    } /* end if */
    else
        if( ( ctPtr = fopen( "transactions.dat", "r" ) ) == NULL)
        {
            printf( "File could not be opened\n" );

        }
    else { /* read account, date,name, balance and SaleAmount from files */
        fscanf( cfPtr, "%d%s%lf", &account, &name, &balance );


        fscanf( ctPtr, "%d%s%lf", &transaccount, &date, &saleamount );
        fscanf( cfPtr2, "%d%s%lf", &newaccount, &newname, &newbalance );
        while ( !feof( cfPtr ) )
        {
            transaccount=1;
            newbalance=balance;
            while ( !feof( ctPtr ) )
            {
                if(transaccount==account&&match==0)
                {
                 newbalance = balance + saleamount;
                 match++;
                }
                else
                    if(transaccount==account&&match>0)
                     newbalance = newbalance + saleamount;

                fscanf( ctPtr, "%d%s%lf", &transaccount, date, &saleamount );
            }
            rewind( ctPtr);
            match=0;

        fprintf( cfPtr2, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, newbalance );
        fscanf( cfPtr, "%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance );
        }

        rewind( cfPtr2);
    }
        fclose( cfPtr2 );
        fclose( cfPtr );
        fclose( ctPtr );
        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I can't believe they're actually still teaching COBOL (under the guise of C), I'll help you out, since, unlike some who seek help here, you've actually put in quite a bit of work :-)

The trick is to not print after every update but rather wait until the account number transitions, the print out the *previous* final details.

And, since you'll reach the end of the transaction file while processing the last account, you'll have to do that one more time after you exit the loop.

Here's the detailed steps.

---

Introduce three more variables, `char lastname[30]`, `int lastaccount` and `double lastbalance`. Ensure that `lastaccount` is initialised to `-1`.

Then your code can catch the transitions of account number by simply checking the values of `lastaccount` and `account`. The storage of all three fields is to ensure that you can print out details for the previous account even though you've already read in the new account details.

---

Before `matches = 1`, insert the following code:

```
if (lastaccount != account) {
    if (lastaccount != -1)
        printf("  %-10d%-10s%.2lf\n", lastaccount, lastname, lastbalance);
    lastaccount = account;
    strcpy (lastname, name);
}
```

You'll also need to include `string.h` to get the prototype for `strcpy`.

This will catch the transitions of account number and print the details for the last one (unless the last one was account number `-1` of course since that means there *is* no previous one). But whether it prints or not, it sets up for the next transition.

---

Immediately after `balance = total`, add `lastbalance = balance;`. This will maintain the most recent balance for the current account so that it can be printed on transition.

Unlike the account number and name, this has to be done for every *transaction* rather than every *account*. That's because the account/name don't change for an account but the closing balance does (for every single transaction).

---

Outside of the loop, immediately before `fclose (cfPtr2);`, put the code:

```
if (lastaccount != -1)
    printf("  %-10d%-10s%.2lf\n", lastaccount, lastname, lastbalance);
```

This prints the details for the final account, assuming that there were any processed at all. As mentioned earlier, this is needed because you'll reach the end of the file without having done a transition due to changed account number.

---

And, please, as a final request:

- get rid of `conio.h` and use `getchar()` instead of `getch()`.
- if *possible,* ditch Turbo C and use `gcc` - it's *so* much better :-)
- don't `fflush(stdin)`.
- use the canonical `int main (void) ...`.
- return something from `main` (although I think that's relaxed in later versions of the standard).

---

I won't post my actual code (unless you guarantee it's not homework) but the following transcript shows that those changes should be enough to fix your current issues:

```
$ cat clients.dat
1 Pax 4.2
2 Roger 0

$ cat transactions.dat
1 1/2/3 112.3
1 2/3/4 -22.1
2 3/4/5 7

$ ./qq
  Account    Name      Balance
|----------------------------------|
  1         Pax       94.40
  2         Roger     7.00
```

---

For what it's worth, I'm not sure I quite agree with treating the tranasction file as the primary element. Since your job is to copy the account file with needed modifications (as specified in the transaction file), I'd prefer to process the account file as the primary unit.

It just seems cleaner to me that way.

And, in the interests of completeness, here's the code I came up with. I wouldn't suggest handing this in as an assignment since there are numerous things likely to get your mark reduced, things that matter a whole lot less in the real world but which educators have a particular bee in their bonnet about :-) Things like multiple return points, using `#define` instead of `enum`, and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HDR_LINE 0
#define HDR_FULL 1

static void outHeader (int withHeading) {
    printf ("+-%-6s-+-%-10s-+-%-6s-+-%-6s-+-%-6s-+\n",
        "------", "----------", "------", "------", "------");
    if (withHeading)
        printf ("| %-6s | %-10s | %-6s | %-6s | %-6s |\n",
            " Acct ", "   Name   ", " Date ", "Amount", "Balnce");
}

static void closeFiles (FILE *pfCli, FILE *pfTxn, FILE *pfNew) {
    if (pfCli) fclose (pfCli);
    if (pfTxn) fclose (pfTxn);
    if (pfNew) fclose (pfNew);
}

static int openFiles (FILE **pfCli, FILE **pfTxn, FILE **pfNew) {
    *pfCli = *pfTxn = *pfNew = NULL;

    if ((*pfCli = fopen ("clients.dat", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ("File clients.dat could not be opened\n");
        closeFiles (*pfCli, *pfTxn, *pfNew);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((*pfTxn = fopen ("transactions.dat", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ("File transactions.dat could not be opened\n");
        closeFiles (*pfCli, *pfTxn, *pfNew);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((*pfNew = fopen ("clientupdate.dat", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf ("File clientupdate.dat could not be opened\n");
        closeFiles (*pfCli, *pfTxn, *pfNew);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

static void outCli (int acct, char *nm, double bal, char *ind) {
    if (acct == -1)
        printf ("| %6s | %-10s | %6s | %6s | %6.2lf | %s\n",
            "", nm, "", "", bal, ind);
    else
        printf ("| %6d | %-10s | %6s | %6s | %6.2lf | %s\n",
            acct, nm, "", "", bal, ind);
}

static void outTxn (char *date, double amt, double bal) {
    printf ("| %6s | %10s | %-6s | %6.2lf | %6.2lf |\n",
        "", "", date, amt, bal);
}

static void getTxn (FILE *fh, int *acct, char *date, double *amt) {
    if (feof (fh))
        *acct = -1;
    else
        fscanf (fh, "%d%s%lf\n", acct, date, amt);
}

static void getCli (FILE *fh, int *last, int *acct, char *nm, double *bal) {
    if (*last != -1)
        outCli (-1, "", *bal, "-->");
    *last = *acct;
    fscanf (fh, "%d%s%lf\n", acct, nm, bal);
}

int main (void) { 
    int cli_acct, txn_acct, last_acct = -1;
    char txn_date[10], cli_nm[10];
    double cli_bal, txn_amt;
    FILE *fCli, *fTxn, *fNew;

    // Open all files, output header and load up first transaction.

    if (!openFiles (&fCli, &fTxn, &fNew))
        return 1;

    outHeader (HDR_FULL);

    getTxn (fTxn, &txn_acct, txn_date, &txn_amt);

    // Process every account.

    while (!feof (fCli)) {
        // Bring in an account and print starting balance.

        getCli (fCli, &last_acct, &cli_acct, cli_nm, &cli_bal);
        outHeader (HDR_LINE);
        outCli (cli_acct, cli_nm, cli_bal, "<--");

        // While account is not yet up to txn, output and read new.

        while (cli_acct < txn_acct) {
            fprintf (fNew, "%d %s %.2lf\n", cli_acct, cli_nm, cli_bal);
            outCli (-1, "", cli_bal, "-->");
            outHeader (HDR_LINE);
            fscanf (fCli, "%d%s%lf\n", &cli_acct, &cli_nm, &cli_bal);
            outCli (cli_acct, cli_nm, cli_bal, "<--");
        }

        // If they don't match, you have a orphan transaction.

        if ((cli_acct != txn_acct) && (txn_acct != -1)) {
            printf ("Orphan transaction for account # %d\n", txn_acct);
            closeFiles (fCli, fTxn, fNew);
            return 1;
        }

        // While account and transaction match, process transaction lines.

        while (cli_acct == txn_acct) {
            cli_bal = cli_bal + txn_amt;
            outTxn (txn_date, txn_amt, cli_bal);
            if (feof (fTxn))
                txn_acct = -1;
            else
                fscanf (fTxn, "%d%s%lf\n", &txn_acct, &txn_date, &txn_amt);
        }
        fprintf (fNew, "%d %s %.2lf\n", cli_acct, cli_nm, cli_bal);
    }

    // Output final lines if needed.

    if (last_acct != -1)
        outCli (-1, "", cli_bal, "-->");
    outHeader (HDR_LINE);

    // Close all files and exit successfully.

    closeFiles (fCli, fTxn, fNew);
    return 0;
}
```

Given the `clients.dat` of:

```
0 Mary 99.9
1 Pax 4.2
2 Bob 7
4 Roger 0
5 Nobody 9
```

and the `transactions.dat` of:

```
1 1/2/3 112.3
1 2/3/4 -22.1
4 3/4/5 7
```

this outputs:

```
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  Acct  |    Name    |  Date  | Amount | Balnce |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|      0 | Mary       |        |        |  99.90 | <--
|        |            |        |        |  99.90 | -->
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 | Pax        |        |        |   4.20 | <--
|        |            | 1/2/3  | 112.30 | 116.50 |
|        |            | 2/3/4  | -22.10 |  94.40 |
|        |            |        |        |  94.40 | -->
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|      2 | Bob        |        |        |   7.00 | <--
|        |            |        |        |   7.00 | -->
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|      4 | Roger      |        |        |   0.00 | <--
|        |            | 3/4/5  |   7.00 |   7.00 |
|        |            |        |        |   7.00 | -->
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|      5 | Nobody     |        |        |   9.00 | <--
|        |            |        |        |   9.00 | -->
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

and creates the `clientupdate.dat` of:

```
0 Mary 99.90
1 Pax 94.40
2 Bob 7.00
4 Roger 7.00
5 Nobody 9.00
```

Feel free to use that code for any purpose other than passing it off as your own homework.

Comment: Appreciate the help so much, Especially the detail steps so that i can actually understand what i need to do! And will Remember to not use conio.h and the likes! thanks again.

Comment: Just changed the code there , It fixed my problem, i understand now that i failed to realise that the most recent balance will need to be kept for the current account being updated. The output is now spot on thanks so much for the help, Now to get cracking on another part of this lab work.

Comment: You're going to hate me but i just tested out some stuff there, The code now works great for printing the results to the screen but for me i am still getting 
1 james 540.00
2 john 662.00
2 john 762.00

wrote in the file rather than just 2 john 762, unfortunately im looking more for the new file to have the update rather than the prints to the screen =(

Comment: I won't hate you for that. Now, if you ran over my _dog,_ that would be a different story :-) Writing them out with `.00` at the end will be fine since they'll still scan in okay. But, if you _really_ want them to be different (and I still would suggest it's unnecessary), you'll need to change the `%.2lf` in your `fprintf(cfPtr2,...` - that's what's forcing the value to two fractional places. You just need to be careful with `%lf` since you may get _more_ precision than you want, like `762.0000000000135`.

Comment: Oh the decimal is no probelm, sorry i was really unclear there , basically the code now prints to the screen the updated information perfectly it doesnt repeated any client, but my updateclient.dat has the second record printed for eg 
the prints to the screen show :
1 james 540.00
2 john 762.00
3 paul 414.00
4 sam 502.00

but the new file contains :
1 james 540.00
2 john 662.00
2 john 762.00
3 paul 414.00
4 sam 502.00

im looking to have the same in both just the updated.
Sorry for being so unclear

Comment: @James, I'd like to suggest that you open up _another_ question with your code as it stands. Since the problem you're describing is a different one, it deserves another question rather than trying to solve it in comments where no-one looks.

Comment: Took your advice, Thanks for getting me this far , really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the update with the code pax, Im going to try adapt it to fit what i already have as i havent dealt with the likes of static void before, even tho i just assume thats just some sort of function header/prototype. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of outputting the results with printf right away, put the results into an array.

Once you are done with your while loops, use for loops to go through the array of stored data and look for duplicate transactions and merge them together printing out merged transactions.

Comment: I Understand what you mean to an extent nick , Except that Printing to the screen is for my own benefit what my main goal is , is to create the new clients file with no duplicates, Its taken me a long time to get to the stage where it will update the balances and fprintf into the file, im not sure im competent enough to store and merge all that information, Ill give it a shot thought, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the problem you've seen is related, but:

1. `fflush(stdin)` gives undefined behavior -- don't do it. If you want to skip everything up to the next new-line, you can do what with `scanf("%*[^\n'");`
2. `while( !feof(ctPtr))` is almost guaranteed to cause problems -- it will generally make it it seem like the last read from the file is happening twice, duplicating the data.

The "duplicate transaction" sounds like it probably stems from the latter.

Comment: Thanks jerry , i wasnt sure on whether flushing was needed in this case, and with regards to the eof ptr i understand that as i had it happen in another part of the assignment... but with regards to the duplicate, i want to have a duplicate transaction in the original transaction file, so that when i read in the two files the Updated client balance will take into consideration both transactions and update the balance accordingly only once, whereas now the output would look like 

1 james 540.00
2 john 662.00
2 john 762.00

where johns second transaction was 100.00